# Express API returning HTML, not JSON, on GET request w/ JWT Token

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I've been trying to wrap my head around this all day. I'm trying to figure out where this token is.... Any ideas?

All I keep getting is the following error and a return in text/html from my Express backend

SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 3

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const { default: mongoose } = require("mongoose");

const auth_routes = require('./routes/auth.routes');
const rate_routes = require('./routes/rate.routes');

dotenv.config();

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const mongo_uri = 'mongodb://' + process.env.MONGO_USER + ':' + process.env.MONGO_PASSWD + '@localhost:27017/home?authSource=admin';

mongoose.connect(mongo_uri)
.then((resp) => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error: ', err.reason)
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: false,
    }),
);
app.use(cors());

app.listen(port, () => { console.log("Server is running on port 5000");});

...
...

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Welcome to the Behemoth API platform")
});

app.set('userToken', userToken);
app.use('/v1/user', auth_routes);
app.use('/v1/rates', rate_routes);
```

rate.routes.js - the api call

```
const express = require('express');
const auth_middle = require('../middleware/auth');
const axios = require("axios");
const router = express.Router();

router.route('/').get(auth_middle, async function (req, res) {
    try {
        let userToken = req.app.get('userToken');
        const reqBody = [ {
              ....
              ....
        } ];

        let rateResponse = await axios.post('https://xxxxxxxx', reqBody, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + userToken
            }
        });

        var StockRate = rateResponse.data.StockData;

        res.send(rateResponse.data);

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.stack);
        res.status(500).send({error: e.message + " / " + e.keyword });
    }

});

module.exports = router;
```

auth.js

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config();

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.headers.authorization);
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];

        jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY);
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.send(401).json({ message: err })
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the line that returns that error?

Comment: @AlexandruDuDu that's about 80% of my problem, I don't even know which line is returning the error.

I'm running https://localhost:5000/v1/rates with my JSON body parsed and my JWT passing through Auth Bearer. /v1/user/signin works no problem. I'm only getting it with my rates route and code but it's not telling me what line/file. This is all I get below

Comment: @AlexandruDuDu

SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 3
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (/home/zombie/behemoth/server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:89:19)
    at /home/zombie/behemoth/server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:128:18
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:202:9)
    at invokeCallback (/home/zombie/behemoth/server/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:231:16)
    at done (/home/zombie/behemoth/server/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:220:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/zombie/behemoth/server/node_modules/raw-body/in

Comment: What's up with that constant `reqBody`?

Comment: I'm not sure if you anonymized the data or it's a js syntax that I'm not familiar with, but it looks weird and that may cause the problem

Comment: @AlexandruDuDu const symbol = req.body.ticker_symbol;
        const exchange = req.body.exchange;
        const currency = req.body.currency;

        const reqBody = [ {
                'ticker_symbol': symbol,
                'stockExchange': exchange,
                'currency_type': currency
        } ];

Comment: @AlexandruDuDu I don't even think it's that it's the route programming itself now. I've trimmed it all out completely just to console.log my req data and I'm still receiving that error, unless it's something to do with Postman.

Comment: @AlexandruDuDu - it was the way I was sending my API data..... I don't know how or what happened, but it looks like the characters were just wrong overall even though it was the same set of data from another API call. I just retyped it all out by hand and it worked.

Comment: maybe you copied in the first place that data from somewhere else and contained a space or a character with an identical aspect but difference ascii code....I'm glad you solved it